# How to Enable the Client-side Logging with the Azure Storage Client Library（Ver 12） for Java

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I want to log the request/response at client site with Azure blob storage for `Java sdk(ver12`).

In microsoft online document [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/client-side-logging-with-the-microsoft-azure-storage-sdk-for-java], I found this sample code.

```
// Set logging off by default.  
OperationContext.setLoggingEnabledByDefault(false);  
OperationContext ctx = new OperationContext();  
ctx.setLoggingEnabled(true);  

// Create an operation to add a new customer to the people table.  
TableOperation insertCustomer1 = TableOperation.insertOrReplace(customer1);  

// Submit the operation to the table service.  
table.execute(insertCustomer1, null, ctx);
```

But it does not work. `OperationContext` can not be found in libs. Maybe it is a older version sample.

I hope someone can give me a sample code, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `OperationContext` is a class of `com.microsoft.azure.storage`, while the latest version is [8.6.3](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage/latest/com/microsoft/azure/storage/OperationContext.html).

You can get the [OperationContext](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/legacy-master/microsoft-azure-storage/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/OperationContext.java) class **in Microsoft Azure Storage SDK v8 for Java**.

If you would like to access our [latest Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java), please refer to the Storage SDK v12 for Java link in the table below. If you would like more information on our decision to upgrade our Java SDK and the path forward, please refer to [this document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/V12%20Upgrade%20Story.md). If you would like more information on Azure's burgeoning effort to coordinate the development of the SDKs across services, of which this change is a part, please refer to this article.